# Autorotate uiviews in cocos2d v2.0

Tags: objective-c, uiview, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos2d v2.0 for game. Since cocosbuilder does not have native text fields, I am using `UITextField`s to allow the user to input text in the menus.

One issue I'm having is that when the device rotates 180 degrees, none of the `UITextField`s are rotating. After a bunch of Googling, I have found plenty of solutions for Cocos2d v1.0, but these are all incompatible with v2.0.

The [cocos2d guide for autorotation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aautorotation) says that the default autorotation uses an opengl call, rather than using a `UIViewController`, since the former is faster. The guide shows how to change this in cocos2d v1.0. How can I do the same in cocos2d v2.0?